# Creating a Native iOS App for an Existing Rails App

Tags: mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ios5, mp3, native

Okay, so I'm running a Rails 3.1 app hosted on engine yard. I'd like to create a **native** iOS app which will run off the same database as the web app.

However, where the web app supports full CRUD, I only want to be able to do two things with the app:

- Fetch data from the database [eg: MP3 Names]
- Play the MP3s within the app.

Any suggestions of frameworks from anyone? :) It'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend on building out the app more, I'd take a look at [RestKit](http://restkit.org/). It has some great stuff included to help cache data on the iphone and synch between iOS and the Rails app.

If you aren't planning on things getting more complicated than what you have described above, you may be better off using something a little more lightweight check out [RestClient](https://github.com/jeremylightsmith/RestClient) or [LRResty](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRResty)